# Correct way to loop through a list in R

Tags: r, statistics, topology

I currently have a list of persistent diagrams with the following structure -

```
str(result)
List of 19
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ DiagGrid1:List of 4
  ..$ DiagGrid2:List of 4
```

i.e. 19 tuples of Diagrams which correspond to 19 .csv files containing two classes of curves (Approach and Retract). I would like to create a 38x38 distance matrix with the `bottleneck()` function -

```
bottleneck(result[[1]]$DiagGrid1$diagram, result[[1]]$DiagGrid1$diagram)
```

for all 19 list elements and the tuple combinations between them. Unfortunately, I can't get the `for()` loop correctly, so I'm wondering if someone could point me in the correct direction or just give general advice on this.

Thanks in any case.

The `bottleneck()` function can be found in the `TDA` library. For the loop itself, I have tried the following -

```
num_elements <- length(result)
distance_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = num_elements * 2, ncol = num_elements * 2)

for (i in 1:num_elements) {
  for (j in 1:num_elements) {
    diag_grid1_i <- result[[i]]$DiagGrid1$diagram
    diag_grid2_i <- result[[i]]$DiagGrid2$diagram
    diag_grid1_j <- result[[j]]$DiagGrid1$diagram
    diag_grid2_j <- result[[j]]$DiagGrid2$diagram
    
    distance_matrix[i, j] <- bottleneck(diag_grid1_i, diag_grid2_j)
    distance_matrix[i + num_elements, j + num_elements] <-  bottleneck(diag_grid1_j, diag_grid2_i)
  }
}
```

The output of `dput(result[1:2])` is too long and crashed the site on my side but I can provide this, if that helps.

```
str(result[[1]]$DiagGrid1)
List of 4
 $ diagram      : 'diagram' num [1:1494, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "dimension" "Birth" "Death"
  ..- attr(*, "maxdimension")= num 1
  ..- attr(*, "scale")= num [1:2] 6.63e-05 3.21e-04
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language gridDiag(X = matrices$X, FUN = knnDE, lim = cbind(Xlim, Ylim), by = by,      sublevel = TRUE, library = "Dionysus| __truncated__ ...
 $ birthLocation: num [1:1494, 1:2] 160.8 160.8 0 0 26.7 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ deathLocation: num [1:1494, 1:2] 13.8 160.8 13.2 0 145.3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ cycleLocation:List of 1494
  ..$ : num[0 , 0 , 1:2] 
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 160.8 160.8 -12.4 -12
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 0 158 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 0 0 -12.4 -12.3
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 26.65 147.75 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 27 26.65 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 28 27 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 26.3 26.65 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 27.65 28 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 25.3 26.3 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 27.35 27 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 26 26.3 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 25.65 26 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 29.35 28.05 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 24.95 25.25 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 29.05 29.35 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 28.35 28.05 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 28.7 29.05 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 32.45 29.35 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 29.7 29.35 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 31.45 29.7 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 30.05 29.7 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 33.85 32.45 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 31.1 31.45 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 30.75 31.1 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 30.45 30.75 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 32.15 32.45 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 24.65 24.95 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 31.8 31.45 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 34.15 33.85 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 33.5 33.85 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 35.2 34.15 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 33.15 33.5 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 34.5 34.2 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 35.55 35.2 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 34.85 34.5 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 32.8 32.5 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 36.55 35.6 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 35.85 35.6 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 36.9 36.55 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 36.2 36.55 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 24.4 24.6 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 37.95 36.9 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 38.65 37.95 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 40 38.65 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 37.25 36.9 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 37.55 37.25 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 39.3 38.65 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 24.1 24.4 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 38.3 38.65 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 41.35 40 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 38.95 39.3 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 40.35 40 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 41 40.35 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 40.65 41 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 42.35 41.35 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 39.65 39.3 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 43.05 42.35 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 41.7 41.35 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 42.7 43.05 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 42 42.35 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 44 43.05 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 43.7 44 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 47.1 44 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 43.35 43.05 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 44.4 44.05 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 23.8 24.05 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 45.75 44.4 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 45.1 45.75 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 45.45 45.75 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 48.8 47.1 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 44.75 44.4 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 46.8 47.1 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 48.5 48.8 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 48.1 48.5 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 46.45 46.8 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 46.1 45.75 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 47.8 48.1 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 49.1 48.8 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 49.85 49.1 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 47.45 47.15 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 50.15 49.85 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 49.5 49.15 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 51.15 50.2 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 50.5 50.2 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 23.5 23.75 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 54.2 51.15 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 51.5 51.15 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 50.8 51.15 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 51.85 51.5 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 52.85 51.85 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 52.15 51.85 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 23.2 23.5 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 55.25 54.2 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 53.2 52.85 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 52.5 52.85 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 53.5 53.2 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 55.9 55.25 -7.45 -7.45
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1, 1:2] 54.9 55.2 -7.45 -7.45
  .. [list output truncated]
```

Basically I need to loop through `result[[1]]` to `result[[19]]` and consider all tuples of `DiagGrid1, DiagGrid2`.

Comment: The `str`-output is not quite enough to help making the distance matrix. Are you able to share the output from (say) `dput(result[1:2])`? Where is `bottleneck` defined? Finally, you say you could not get the `for` loop to work ... please show the `for`-loop code so we can help with it.